# Unprefixed verbs of motion

Tags: грамматика, motion-verbs

I understand that a different verb of motion is used for a bus, tram, train than for a car, lorry, van.
e.g.автобус ходит, машина ездит

Is this correct and, if so, why? Then, if I get on the bus автобус ходит а я еду.
I'm confused.

Comment: Think of the fixed schedule of a bus route (or any public transport, except airplane) - use ходит. If it's a physically moving bus - it's едет, ездит.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite. Автобус **едет** if all you mean is that it's in motion.

Автобус **ходит** — as does all other non-airborne public transport, including passenger ships — in relation to its route or destination.

Thus you say,

> **Из Москвы в Балашиху ходит электричка**

— meaning you can get to Balashikha from Moscow by commuter train. But:

> **Вот едет электричка из Москвы в Балашиху**

— of an actual train passing by, or of a hypothetical but *specific* train.

Comment: For a plane, is it always самолёт

Comment: For a plane, is it always самолёт едет or maybe самолёт летит never самолёт идёт

Comment: Самолет летит, not идет.

Comment: For a plane, you can use летает for "there is a regular flight" and летит for a plane currently flying